# Problema al desplegar aplicacion web ya desarrollada

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, mysqlconnector, ant

hace 5 años desarolle una aplicacion web con su front end y su backend con al capa logica desarrollada en Java. La tenia comprimida y almacenada en la nube, y he querido desplegarla de nuevo en un ordenador diferente donde la desarrolle en su dia, y no consigo implementarla bien. La quiero desplegar en Tomcat, pero veia errores en las consultas de la base de datos, por eso al final la he abierto en netbeans para ir buscando los errores mas detenidamente. Me lanza un error que indica:
**C:\Users\Raul\Documents\ViewsBackEnd\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1000: Warning: Could not find file C:\Users\Raul\Documents\ViewsBackEnd${libs.MySQLDriver.classpath} to copy.**

Y si pincho en ese error, me lleva a la linea del archivo build, que indica:
`<copyfiles files="${libs.MySQLDriver.classpath}" todir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>`

Yo he revisado mi proyecto original, y no he tenido nunca un directorio /lib dentro de la carpeta WEB-INF.
El proyecto funcionaba perfectamente y no he tocado nada en todos estos años.

Si me pudierias dar ideas os lo agradeceria mucho.

Saludos!

Comment: Esta buscando un driver que parece que no tenes instalado...

Comment: Ok pero no lo entiendo, tengo instalado en el proyecto .jar del conector de mysql para jdbc, y salvo que se me pase algo con ese driver es suficiente para que conecte con MySql server la aplicacion no?. Gracias

Comment: Bueno me he cargado esa libreria y ya deja compilar el proyecto. Pero no entiendo nada la verdad, si iba todo bien en su dia, ahora no deja de dar errores. Pero bueno al menos deja seguir trabajando en el proyecto. Gracias, saludos!

Comment: El problema podria estar en la version de la JVM del servidor, Corre en Tomcat, Glassfish, etc? Se cambio la version de MYSQL (5.x, 8.x)? Generalmente es el sufrimiento normal cuando se olvida algun desarrollo por años y luego se retoma, siempre hay problemas por las versiones de JVM o de la DB. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Nestor, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ayer estaba empezando a deducir que es podria ser el problema. Por eso el control de versiones, pero hasta que no le pasa a uno personalmente no lo vive jeje. Bueno me pondre a revisar compatibilidad de versiones, actualizar drivers, etc...Muchas gracias de nuevo, saludos!